# Python subprocess Popen periodic callback

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I am running an HPC simulation on amazon AWS with spot instances. Spot instances can be terminated with 2 minutes notice by AWS. In order to check for termination you need to exectute `curl` on a spefiic URL every 5 seconds. It is a simple request that returns a json with the termination time, if AWS have initiated the termination process.

Currently I am using `subprocess` to run the script:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True)
for line in p.stdout:
    if "Floating point exception" in line:
        print(line.rstrip())
    log.write(line)
    log.flush()
p.wait()
status = p.returncode
print(status)
```

Is it possible to add a callback that is called every 5 seconds?

The callback would check the return of the `curl` command, if it finds a termination time it would set a flag in a file and exit. The main process will then end gracefully because of this flag.

To clarify, I do not want to interact or kill the main process. This particular process (not written by me) checks continuously the content of a file and exits gracefully if it finds a specific keyword. The callback would set this keyword.

Is this the right approach?

Comment: If the requirement is not necessarily to have real-time output, perhaps just use `p.communicate()` (or simply `subprocess.run()` which removes much of the plumbing you need here) with `timeout=5`?

Comment: Just put your code in a `while` loop and `time.sleep(5)` at the end of it..?

Comment: @vaizki Do you mean just before p.wait()? Would this block the main process?

Comment: @tripleee From here (https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) it seems that timeout is not periodic. Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you mean by "periodic". If you want to poll the same process repeatedly, just `p.communicate(timeout=5)` as many times as you like in a loop. But if as you say you want to call `curl` every 5 seconds, I'm imagining maybe you actually want to terminate it if it doesn't finish in five seconds (in which `subprocess.run(timeout=5)` does that with much less hassle). Anyway, Python can fetch web pages natively; do you really even need a subprocess here?

Comment: I have edited the question. Hopefully it clarifies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a function that runs the following loop;

- launches `curl` in a subprocess and processes the returned JSON.
- If the sim should terminate, it writes the required file and returns.
- Otherwise `sleep` for 4.5 minutes.

Start that function in a `threading.Thread` before you launch the simulation.

You'd have to test what happens to your `for line in p.stdout` loop if the program running in `p` exits.
Maybe it will generate an exception. Or you might want to check `p.poll()` in the loop to handle that gracefully.